# Outlook C# - How do I determine if user replied to a message?

Tags: c#, outlook

In code, I want to get the reply status, the one outlook use to display "You replied to this message on ...".

I tried looking at all MailItem properties but I can't find anything which look like that.

Thanks in advance,
Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string SchemaTransportHeader = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040";

string repliedOn =  oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(SchemaTransportHeader).ToString();
```

It will return empty if it hasn't been replied to or the DateTime that it has.